# Matching a variable with AWK

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

this is my code:

```
awk -v header=$header '{if($0~/header/){if(i>0){printf "\n"$0}else{printf $0}}else{printf "\t"$0};i++}END{printf "\n"}' $1 > $basename1"_tab.tab"
```

However, it maches exactly 'header'' instead of the content of the variable. For example, if I set header='hola', I want the script to match hola instead of header.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
awk -v head="$header" '{if($0~head){if(i>0){printf "\n"$0.....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes to use shell variable

**Example 1#:**

```
rahul@test-srv:~$ u=root
rahul@test-srv:~$ awk "/$u/" /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

**Example 2#**

```
rahul@test-srv:~$ r=rahul
rahul@test-srv:~$ awk  '/'"$r"'/' /etc/passwd
rahul:x:1000:1000:rahul,,,:/home/rahul:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

That is weird. If you change `header` to `h` it works!

```
header=hola; echo hola | awk -v h=$header '/h/{print "Matched"}'
Matched

header=hola; echo hola | awk -v header=$header '/header/{print "Matched"}'
```

And Kent's doesn't seem to work - which is definitely not what I would expect!!!

```
header=hola; echo hola | awk -v header="$header" '/header/{print "Matched"}'
```

Comment: Variable inside `/../` are considered literal. Use `$0~header` instead. When you used `/h/` it matched the `h` in `**h**ola`.

Comment: `h` matched the literal `h` in the line `hola`.